# aastex61 - Single column deluxetable, cannot set width

Tags: tables, aastex, deluxetable

I'm using the lastest aastex61 package along with deluxetables. My table is only about 1/2 a column wide, and I'm trying to get it to takeup the entire column... What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex61}
...
\begin{deluxetable}{r|ccc}[h!]
\tablecolumns{4}
\tablewidth{1.0\columnwidth} 
\tablecaption{Schechter Function Parameters} 
\tablehead{ z & log($\phi^{*}$) &  $\alpha$ &  $M^{*}_{\rm UV}$ }
\startdata
    8 & -3.75 & -2.13 & -20.52 \\
    9 & -3.94 & -2.24 & -20.39 \\
    10 & -4.13 & -2.35 & -20.25 \\ 
    11 & -4.29 & -2.47 & -20.11 \\ % Extrapolated from here
    12 & -4.49 & -2.58 & -19.98 \\
    13 & -4.69 & -2.69 & -19.84 \\
    14 & -4.89 & -2.81 & -19.71 \\
    15 & -5.08 & -2.92 & -19.57 \\
    16 & -5.28 & -2.03 & -19.44 \\
\enddata  
\label{tab:schecParams}
\tablecomments{Table comments.}
\end{deluxetable}
```

It still looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... You can use symmetric `\hspace{}` to accomplish this. See the code below. Adding `\hspace` before the label but within the column header does it. Then you need `\hspace` OUTSIDE the `\colhead` to balance it if you want things centered.

```
\begin{deluxetable}{r|ccc}
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablecolumns{2} 
\tablecaption{\label{tab:sims}Simulations} 
\tablehead{\colhead{Name} & \colhead{\hspace{.75cm}$Z_{\rm crit}$}\hspace{.5cm} & \colhead{\hspace{.5cm}$f_{w}$\tablenotemark{a}}\hspace{.75cm} & \colhead{\hspace{.33cm}Pop III IMF}\hspace{.33cm} } 
\startdata
fid & $10^{-5}$ & 10 & Salpeter\tablenotemark{b}\\
Z4 & $10^{-4}$ & 10 & Salpeter\\
Z6 & $10^{-6}$ & 10 & Salpeter\\
P3SN & $10^{-5}$ & 10 & Log normal\tablenotemark{c}\\
fw1 & $10^{-5}$ & 1 & Salpeter\\
\enddata 
\tablenotetext{\tiny a}{This is the ``SN mass loading'' denotes the amount of gas, expressed in muplitples of the mass of SN ejecta, carried along with the SN blast and removed from the host cell.}
\tablenotetext{\tiny b}{The Salpeter IMF has power-law slope $\alpha=-2.35$ and spans 0.1 to 100 M$_{\odot}$.}
\tablenotetext{\tiny c}{The log normal IMF has a characteristic mass of 60 M$_{\odot}$ with $\sigma = 1$. The mass range spans 1 to 500 M$_{\odot}$.}
%\tablecomments{\small Comments will be included after a the table.}
\end{deluxetable}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i wish i could just post this as a comment, but i don't have enough reputation yet (sorry in advance SO gods):

i work for the AAS editorial team. `deluxetable` was designed to produce the tightest possible table layout and to prevent issues with `tabular` tables that have excess space or that overflow columns.

so based on this design as well as my attempts to try the tricks I knew, I don't think you can force `deluxetable` tables to overflow their maximum derived width and you'd do better to rebuild it in something like `tabular` or `longtable` if you really want the table to fill the column width.

or you can open an issue here, and we will take it under consideration for our next round of development: [github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues](https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues)

Comment: Thank @Gus, I appreciate the insight. I'll just switch to a 'tabular' ...